# c++ CLI: get HKEY from SafeRegistryHandle

Tags: c++-cli, registrykey

I work with the registry and use the function RegNotifyChangeKeyValue. The first option requires registry key handle (HKEY), but I have RegistryKey, from which I can get SafeRegistryKey (key->Handle).

```
RegistryKey^ key = myKey;
        RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(key->Handle, true, dwFilter, events[i], true);
```

Error: "argument of type "Microsoft::Win32::SafeHandles::SafeRegistryHandle" is incompatible with parameter of type "HKEY""

How do I get HKEY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conversion is required to get from the wrapped `IntPtr` in the safe-handle class to the native handle.  It looks like this:

```
   HKEY handle = (HKEY)key->Handle->DangerousGetHandle().ToPointer();
```

You do get to fret over the word "Dangerous" in the method name, it is aptly named.  There is nothing that the CLR can do to ensure that the handle stays valid until you no longer need the change notifications.  It is now your job to ensure that the `key` object reference stays visible and the garbage collector won't collect it too early.

It cannot be a local variable, it *could* be a member of a class but that in turn requires the class object to stay referenced.  Storing it in a `static` variable is the safest way, calling GCHandle::Alloc() is the next best way, maybe you need `gcroot<>`.  There's no context in the question to make the call.